# How do I improve current style of the table

Tags: html, html-table, responsive-design

Could you please give me some advice on how I can improve the look of the current table. Right now, due to the number of contents crammed in a column, it does not look appealing in terms of the table.

What would be an efficient way to do this?

Thank you and here is the image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D51qH.png)

Answer (score 1):

It is better if you can use bootstrap table.
Try on this.It is responsive also.
Regards.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a simple table.

It's okay for big screens to have content horizontally aligned.

For mobile screens the description should come below the name..

[W3-row](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_responsive.asp) would allow that.